# Как запланировать задачу на Flask?

Tags: python, flask, cron, celery

Пытаюсь организовать задачу, но если прохожу по ссылке **/test_task**, то пока все не отпринтуется - я не получу на странице результат  **{'status': True}**

```
from flask import Flask
App = Flask(__name__)

from celery import Celery
App.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
App.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'

celery = Celery(App.name, broker=App.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(App.config)

@celery.task
def task_print_msg(counter):
    for i in range(counter):
        print('+ +', i*10, '+ +')


@App.route('/test_task', methods=['GET'])
def test_task():
    print('=== test_task ===')
    for i in range(100000):
        print('send', i)
        task_print_msg(i)
    return jsonify({'status': True})
```

Он же мне должен дать ответ, а сам сидеть и принтовать. Или я что-то не так реализую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для вызова отложенной задачи вы должны использовать apply_async/delay.

```
@App.route('/test_task', methods=['GET'])
def test_task():
    print('=== test_task ===')
    for i in range(100000):
        print('send', i)
        task_print_msg.delay(i)
    return jsonify({'status': True})
```

подробнее: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/calling.html

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delay'
--

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил пример.